# Bootstrap guidelines for form preview/details pages

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm exploring Bootstrap and I've found many guidelines, articles and Stack Overflow questions about forms. It's well described topic. However I cannot find much information about organizing preview pages.

Basically after user submits some form there's possibility to see a preview/details of saved data. Those views contain mostly labels, namely labels for names and labels for values. Sometimes tables and other data. [Here's an example.](https://petecrm2011.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/preview-screen.png)

Often preview/details pages have horizontal layout. In case of forms there's `form-horizontal` class in Bootstrap, but is there any guidelines for preview/details pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#horizontal-description) is documented how to deal with presenting data on preview/details pages in a form like:

```
Name:        Something
Price:       $200
Producer:    Company
```

It's simple and here's an example:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Name:</dt><dd>{{ foo.Name }}</dd>
    <dt>Price:</dt><dd>{{ foo.Price}}</dd>
    <dt>Producer:</dt><dd>{{ foo.Producer}}</dd>
</dl>
```

There's also vertical version documented [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#description).